# Is there a way to make an absolute positioned div draggable to a wider width using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, drag

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EEtVU/) I have an example of a `div` that is animated on click to expand its width. Is there anyway I can achieve this with a drag instead of a click?

What I'd really like to have is a draggable item that if the user drags it 75px out of the 100px width, it autocompletes the drag animation like in iOS's notification bar.

current jQuery:

```
$('.handle').toggle(
    function() { $('.bar').animate({right: 0, opacity: 1.0}, { duration: 0, queue: false }); }, 
    function() { $('.bar').animate({right: -165, opacity: 0.6}, { duration: 0, queue: false }); }
);

$('.handle').toggle(
    function() { $('.handle').animate({right: 200, opacity: 1.0}, { duration: 0, queue: false }); }, 
    function() { $('.handle').animate({right: 35, opacity: 0.6}, { duration: 0, queue: false }); }
);​
```

Comment: Did you check http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need JQueryUI or some other similar plugins to accomplish that. With that you can make your bar draggable by using $('.handle').draggable();

In case you don't want to use any other plugins you might be interested in this:

[draggable-div-without-jquery-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569095/draggable-div-without-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Well your jsfiddle example is somewhat foggy to me, either is your goal but what I've understood you want something like this, right? This thing is somewhat tweaky it really depends on your UI and also could become quite buggy depending on your code either.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Tn2F/

```
var bar = $(".bar");
bar.draggable({
    start:function(){
    }
}).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).animate({left:300, opacity: 0.6}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
});
$(".handle").droppable({
    over: function( event, ui ) {
        bar.trigger( 'mouseup' );

    }
});
```

The code above is based on the jsfiddle example I've provided but is customizable to your case.

BR