# Moveable div but only div header to move all of div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to make an app looks like windows explorer. I was search what i need to build my app.

1. dragable
2. ajax for request
3. etc.

for ajax i was found. and it work as well.
but i have problem with jquery moveable div (*I found it from csstrick*)
you can see what i was did from codepen with this [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqjgI)

my question is :
how to create jquery movable but only header can move a whole div.?
please dont suggest me to use jquery ui or jquery easy ui. i just want to build my app from 0, not using ready framework like ui/easyui.
i dont know much about jquery/javascript. but with this app, i want to learn, that why i'm not using ui/easyui.

if you have link/google suggest keyword pleas tell me.
sorry for my grammer or my language.

Thanks for adv.

EDIT 1:

let say for dummy code is like this.

```
<div class="move">
<div class="title">This is title</div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

if i use code from csstrick like what i was doing in example in codepen. i can move div in `move` area. but i want is i can move `move` div just from `.title`.

EDIT 2.
This [LINK](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui) is original csstrick script

EDIT 3.

I was found what i want.

[Draggable div without jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569095/draggable-div-without-jquery-ui)

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery UI, at least study the source code for plugins you are interested in to understand how they work.

Comment: i was read carefuly code from csstrick, but i realy blank about jquery/javascript. so i need more example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely on your code:

```
opt = $.extend({handle:"",}, opt);
    //if handle is empty drag by its container, else with the handle element
    if(opt.handle === "") {
        var $el = this;
    } else {
        var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
    }
```

As you can see you can specify a `selector` to **handle** the dragging, just need to pass your header selector.

```
$('.widget').drags({handle:".title"});
```

Updated your pen: [**codepen.io/anon/pen/sdBwo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sdBwo)

Comment: wow. thanks. i learning somethin' new here. thanks for your explain. for next time i'll read code more carefuly.