# Drag div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div draggable without using jQuery UI.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="toddler"></div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$.fn.slider = function () {
$(this).on("mousedown", function () {
    $dragging = true;
});

$(this).on("mouseup", function () {
    $dragging = null;
});

$(this).on("mousemove", function () {
    if ($dragging) {
        $(this).offset({
            left: $(this).pageX
        });
    }
});
};

$(".toddler").slider();
```

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jge9z/2022/)

but my code doesn't work. What's wrong? How to make it work?

Comment: Do you define `$dragging` somewhere?

Comment: I tried to change my code http://jsfiddle.net/Jge9z/2027/ but it doesn't work too (

Comment: Here's an old question with a working fiddle answer -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569095/draggable-div-without-jquery-ui

Comment: I've seen it, but I would like to make my code work

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($) {
$.fn.drags = function(opt) {

    opt = $.extend({handle:"",cursor:"move"}, opt);

    if(opt.handle === "") {
        var $el = this;
    } else {
        var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
    }

    return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
        } else {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
        }
        var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
            drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
            drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
            pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
            pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
        $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) {
            $('.draggable').offset({
                top:e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
            }).on("mouseup", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
    }).on("mouseup", function() {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
        }
    });

}
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('div').drags();
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use jqueryUI. You can drag without it but it will not give the smoothness which can only be provided by jqueryUI.

Examples

[Link 1](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/mkUJf/)

[Link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Jge9z/)

So i suggest to use any drag plugin to give smoothness to your function.

Function used

```
$(function() {
$('body').on('mousedown', 'div', function() {
    $(this).addClass('draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function(e) {
        $('.draggable').offset({
            top: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() / 2,
            left: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() / 2
        }).on('mouseup', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('mouseup', function() {
    $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable');
});
});
```

Comment: I tried to use solution from Link 2, but when I tried to use `position()` instead of `offset()` it doesn't work. What's wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/Jge9z/2054/