# Looking for a feature that enables me to drag a particular Navigation Menu anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a feature that allow me to mouse click on a Navigation Menu and drag it. Suppose, if I have navigation menus such as HOME, ABOUT US, PROFILE, SERVICES & CONTACT US and among these menus if I click on HOME nav menu (without releasing the clicked mouse) and be able to drag it around the page upto a limited height of the page. When I say limited height, say upto the height of a particular banner with the height of 680px.

I tried to search on the net but was unable to find anything related to this funtionality or feature and do not know if such a thing can be created.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with any such feature and if yes then how can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.  CJ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447920/drag-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

There is no plugin that I know of, or something already done, because this appears to be a simple drag and drop problem. I would recommend reading the guides [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/) and implementing your own drag and drop for this problem.

Comment: @SijoJose Welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure to check out the tour [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) which will give you info on how to earn rep and will get you your first badge on the website. In this case, be sure to accept answers (Using the green checkmark) to earn rep and use that rep for additional privileges on the website.