# Tell if mouse was dragged from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

My page contains a red and a blue `div`:

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

They're both absolutely positioned and are separated by a small amount:

```
#red {
    background-color: red;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5em;
    top: 5em;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15em;
    top: 5em;
}
```

I have some code to tell if the user clicks and drags their mouse from one `div` to the other:

```
$('#red').mousedown( function () {
    $('#blue').mouseup( function () {
        alert('Red to Blue')
    })
})

$('#blue').mousedown( function () {
    $('#red').mouseup( function () {
        alert('Blue to Red')
    })
})
```

This works perfectly the first time if the user moves the mouse directly from one `div` to the other with the mouse button held down.

There are 2 issues though:

1. If the user releases the mouse button while outside of a `div` then clicks on the other one, `mouseup` will still run.
2. Any time after the first, the user will have to click outside of either `div` in order for the handlers to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mouseup` event should be removed as soon as it happens (using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)), and it should be detected outside of the divs. In addition we need to prevent the default behavior of `mousedown` by using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to fix the 2nd problem. See comments in code.

Note: [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (one not on) is used to bind a one time event handler, that is removed as soon as it's fired. This prevents multiple attachments of the `mouseup` event to the document.

```js
var $red = $('#red')
var $blue = $('#blue');

$($.merge($red, $blue)).mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior of mousedown
  var source = $(e.target);

  // attach the mouseup to the document as one time event to detect up
  $(document).one('mouseup', function(e) {
    // check if the source is red and the target is blue
    if ($blue.is(e.target) && source.is($red)) {
      alert('Red to Blue');
    } // check if the source is red and the target is blue
      else if ($red.is(e.target) && source.is($blue)) {
      alert('Blue to Red');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5em;
  top: 5em;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15em;
  top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red"></div>

<div id="blue"></div>
```

And a more universal solution that uses `data-*` attributes to identify the source and the target:

```js
$('[data-color]').mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior of mousedown
  var source = $(e.target).attr('data-color'); // get the source data color

  // attach the mouseup to the document as one time event to detect up
  $(document).one('mouseup', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr('data-color'); // 
    
    if(target !== undefined && source !== target) {
      alert(source + ' to ' + target);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div[data-color] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}

#red {
  left: 5em;
  top: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}

#blue {
  left: 15em;
  top: 1em;
  background-color: blue;
}

#yellow {
  left: 5em;
  top: 10em;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#green {
  left: 15em;
  top: 10em;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- set data-type with the color to each element -->
<div id="red" data-color="Red"></div>

<div id="blue" data-color="Blue"></div>

<div id="yellow" data-color="Yellow"></div>

<div id="green" data-color="Green"></div>
```

Comment: @Drown - no worried, and thanks again for the typo correction.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your approach like this:

```
var isDragging = false;
var dragElement = null;

$('#red, #blue').mousedown(function() {
   dragElement = $(this);
   isDragging = true;
});

$('#red, #blue').mouseup(function() {
    if(isDragging && dragElement){ 
        alert('Dragged in',dragElement);
        dragElement = null;
        isDragging = false;
    }
});

$('body *:not(#red, #blue)').mouseup(function() {
    if(isDragging && dragElement){ 
        alert('Not dragged',dragElement);
        dragElement = null;
        isDragging = false;
    }
});
```

There is an another question about it : [Draggable div without jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569095/draggable-div-without-jquery-ui)

Comment: what if `mouseup` occur outside `red` and `blue`?

Comment: Edited for this case